# Which version control tool is best suited for storing only last 'N' commits?

Tags: version-control

I would like to store one large file which is updated daily.
I am interested in storing only last 'N' versions of this file.
Which version control tool is best suited for this task ?

If not version control tool, is there any other free/open source tool available for this task?

Comment: This feature was built directly into the filesystem of VAX/VMS... Boy I'm getting old.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you mind rewriting the repository periodically. If you don't, you can use Mercurial, with, for example `hg convert` to periodically rewrite the repos to discard older revisions.

Comment: How costly is "hg convert" on repo with large files( ~2GB each ) ?

Comment: @Prafulla: But costly, I assume you mean how fast? I don't know, but you could experiment. Note of course that mercurial, like other version control systems, does not cope well with large binary files or diffs between them, so if that is your use case, I suggest you look elsewhere.